# Sharing const variables across FAKE fsx scripts

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Is there any way to share a variable by including a fsx script within another fsx script.

e.g script buildConsts.fsx contains

```
let buildDir = "./build/"
```

I want to reference this in other build scripts e.g.

```
#load @".\buildConsts.fsx"
let testDlls = !! (buildDir + "*Test*.dll")
```

When I attempt to run the script the 'buildDir' variable the script fails to compile.

This is a fairly common approach that is used with tools such as MSBuild and PSAKE to modularise scripts.  Is this the correct approach with FAKE ?

Comment: That looks like it is the problem... error is The namespace or module 'buildConsts' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing should work - what exactly is the error message that you're getting?

I suspect that the problem is that F# automatically puts the contents of a file in a module and you need to open the module before you can access the constants. The module is named based on the file name, so in your case `buildConsts.fsx` will generate a module named `BuildConsts`. You should be able to use it as follows:

```
#load @".\buildConsts.fsx"
open BuildConsts

let testDlls = !! (buildDir + "*Test*.dll")
```

You can also add an explicit module declaration to `buildconsts.fsx`, which is probably a better idea as it is less fragile (won't change when you rename the file):

```
moule BuildConstants

let buildDir = "./build/"
```